# Merging a bunch of IF and AND formulas in Excel?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Is there a way to merge these formulas into one?

I'm trying to conditionally format rows to be a particular colour.

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TR",$B1))),($F1<>""))
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TR",$B1))),(AND($F1<>"",$G1<>"")))
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TR",$B1))),(AND($F1<>"",$G1<>"",$H1<>"")))
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TR",$B1))),(AND($F1<>"",$G1<>"",$H1<>"",$I1<>""))
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TR",$B1))),(AND($F1<>"",$G1<>"",$H1<>"" ,$I1<>"",$J1<>"")))
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TR",$B1))),(AND($F1<>"",$G1<>"",$H1<>"",$I1<>"",$J1<>"",$K1<>"")))
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TR",$B1))),(AND($F1<>"",$G1<>"",$H1<>"",$I1<>"",$J1<>"",$K1<>"",$L1<>"")))
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TR",$B1))),(AND($F1<>"",$G1<>"",$H1<>"",$I1<>"",$J1<>"",$K1<>"",$L1<>"",$M1<>"")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on HOW you want to use it in detail, it may be different...

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TR",$B1))),AND($F1:F1<>""))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to check if all cells in range are non-empty instead of the long way like this

```
AND($F1<>"", $G1<>"", $H1<>"", $I1<>"", $J1<>"", $K1<>"", $L1<>"", $M1<>"")
```

The easiest way is

```
COUNTA($F1:$M1) <> 0
```

or

```
COUNTBLANK($F1:$M1)=0
```

You can also use [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7). Enter `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TR", $B1))), NOT(ISBLANK($F1:$M1)))` then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Another solution is using `SUMPRODUCT`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($F1:$M1<>"")) <> 0
```

Comment: You should note the behavior for cells containing formulas which are returning empty strings...